# TFS Authorization using Windows Credentials

Tags: windows, authentication, tfs

I am trying to connect my TFS Account on

https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection

I have access to this if I try to go through browser. My windows credentials and TFS credentials are same. I am trying to use my windows credentials to programmatically login into TFS.

Library I am using is :- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client (version 14.0.0, Framework version 4.6.0)

I am not sure if anything else needed to be done for that or this much is sufficient? Something to be done in web.config or app.config or anywhere else? 
Most annoying this is, everything seems same to me in an old project in the same solution and it is working fine.

Getting exception:-

**TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.**

Code:-

```
  public TfsTeamProjectCollection ConnectionVSO { get; set; }

  public TFSRepository()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");
        try
        {        
            var credentials = new AadCredential();
            var clientCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(credentials) { AllowInteractive = false };
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri, clientCredentials);

            if (teamProjectCollection != null)
            {
                teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
            }
            ConnectionVSO = teamProjectCollection;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

I am sure I am missing something. But not sure what? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that was not the issue of code at all. everything was fine. It was the issue of repository of my code. I changed the mapped path of my code on hard drive and got the latest code and it worked. Weird but true :( !! It is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to VSTS, your credential is supposed to stored in Web Credential not Windows Credential if you stored it.

You may createa VssConnection instance to get HttpClients for REST services, or create a TfsTeamProjectCollection instance to use SOAP object model for authenticating VSTS. You can use the following ways to achieve it:

- Azure Active Directory Authentication for REST services
- Personal Access Token authentication for REST services
- Visual Studio sign-in prompt (Microsoft Account or Azure Active
  Directory backed) for REST services
- OAuth Authentication for REST services
- Azure Active Directory authentication for SOAP services
- Basic authentication for SOAP services
- Visual Studio sign-in prompt (Microsoft Account or Azure Active
  Directory backed) for SOAP services

Details: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples#authenticating-visual-studio-team-services

Comment: thanks Cece for the reply. But it didn't help me. Actually, there are two web projects in my solution. First one is older one (pre-written code in Web Form) that is using a common service project to make a call to VSO TFS. That is working fine. But I added a new web project ( MVC ) to the solution and that one is also using the same service project to make a call to VSO TFS. That is not authorized to do so. Everything is same except the calling project. I matched the web.config of both the projects as well. An I missing something in environment ?

Comment: Is the old project and new project using the same credential? Will the sign-in prompt before you get error?

Comment: ya they are in the same solution. the only difference is, old project is on MVC and new project is .net Core. After all the investigations, I came to know that libraries are different in Core for Active directory and TFS Client. I am not able to find out the example or the classes name to be used.

Comment: I have figure out my mistake. Mine is not Web Application. Its web API Application. It does not have user authentication when we access api. I need to figure out how to authenticate user in web api. sorry @cece-msft for misguiding you.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the credentials to TFS(in the above code) from HttpContext.User.Identity ? I can get the access to the user details from this object but I need same user to authenticate on TFS. Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: Using Basic Authentication for SOAP doesn't work with the Service Account. I really hate TFS and M$ right now

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT not sure if you realized it but the TF30063 error is what was introduced to kill off TFVC and force it's userbase to switch to to git. Maybe not intentionally but that's what happened.